# I have stored a pdf file as a blob, an when I try to render it as a pdf in the browser

Tags: grails

I have a domain class

```
class UploadSyllabus {
    String semester
    Course course
    Department department
    byte[] uploadSyllabus
}
```

where Course, Department are other domain classes

In my `Show.gsp` page

```
<a style="margin-left: 108px;"href="javascript:getPdfFromDB()" id="downloadPdf">Download_Syllabus.pdf</a>


function getPdfFromDB(){
    var formdata = $("#downloadSyllabusForm").serialize();
    $.get("${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}/uploadSyllabus/getPdfFromDBC", formdata, function(response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("subjectResult").innerHTML=response
            document.getElementById("courseResult").innerHTML=$("#course option:selected").text();
            document.getElementById("semesterResult").innerHTML=$("#semester option:selected").text();
        }
    });
}
```

My controller's action:

```
def getPdfFromDBC = {
    def sem = params.semester
    def course = params.course
    def department = params.department
    List s= UploadSyllabus.executeQuery("select id from UploadSyllabus where department_id = "+params.department +"AND course_id = "+params.course + "AND semester = "+sem)
    def product = UploadSyllabus.get(s[0])
    println "product is ---"+product
    response.contentType = 'application/pdf'
    response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'Attachment; filename=uploadSyllabus.pdf')
    response.getOutputStream().write(product.uploadSyllabus)
    response.getOutputStream().flush()
    // render s.name as SHALLOW
}
```

What I need to do that I have three dropdown in my view page and when I select 3 of them and click on download link then particular pdf that had been uploaded in database needs to be downloaded.

When I run my code I'm not  getting any error but getting "the page become irresponsive. please kill or wait on browser."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot insert pdf in  document.getElementById("subjectResult").innerHTML=response

if you want to render pdf in html use pdf.js

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: xfermi : thanx alot . i understood the problem .Code is  working now :)